# Gimbal motor shaft

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

Does anyone know if a shaft can be pressed into a gimbal motor like [this](https://www.robotshop.com/en/ipower-gbm5208h-200t-gimbal-motor.html)? Is the centre metal ring just the inner race of a ball bearing?

[image]

[image]

The ring looks thicker on one side but thinner on another though.

Thanks

Comment: @jsotola Yes, that centre metal ring spins as well though. I have something similar but I can't seem to take it apart. The two layers might be pressed together on mine.

Comment: @jsotola I just wanted to know what that ring is about first before pressing a shaft into it. Surprisingly noone seems to have torn down a gimbal motor.

Comment: @jsotola Indeed, I've seen slip rings fitted inside them. But if it's the inner race of a bearing, then it should be able to hold a shaft, I think.

Comment: try asking RobotShop for a datasheet

Comment: one other thought crossed my mind ... maybe the two screws, shown in the bottom picture, are accessible through the holes in the top picture

Comment: have a really close look at the ring with the 4 holes ... it may be a nut

Comment: @jsotola Yeah I'm not sure what those 4 holes are for. Mine doesn't have them though, but mine is much smaller and costs much less.